# shopify display selected variant price

Tags: javascript, html, forms, shopify, liquid

I have rendered the product variants as radio buttons on liquid. Now I am trying to listen to the variant change and render different prices accordingly. However, I do not know how to listen to the variant change here.
Here is my code:

```
<form>
   {% for product_option in product.options_with_values %} 
      {{ product_option.name }}
     
        {% for value in product_option.values %}
            <input type="radio" id = "{{ value }}" name="{{ product_option.name}}" value="{{ value }}" >
            <label for="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</label>  
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    {% assign current = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>Price: {{current.price}} </p> 
    <input type="number" min="1"> 
    <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

The price only shows for the first available variant. Even when I select different radio button options, the variant price does not update.

Comment: Almost all themes come with this built-in. What theme are you using where this is not built-in?

Comment: I am doing this from scratch.

Comment: Use a working theme as your guide then.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow

Ideally, you probably should use some classes to use for your listeners as the page can have different radio buttons possibly even in other forms.

Below probably would get you going in the right direction.

```
<form>
   {% for product_option in product.options_with_values %} 
      {{ product_option.name }}
        {% for value in product_option.values %}
            <input class="option" type="radio" id = "{{ value }}" name="{{ product_option.name}}" value="{{ value }}" >
            <label for="{{ value }}">{{ value }}</label>  
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    {% assign current = product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>Price: <span id="variantPrice">{{current.price}}</span></p> 
    <input type="number" min="1"> 
    <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

You haven't mentioned if you are using jquery or not.
I'm going to assume you are.

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     // Load all product data to an object
     var productData = {{ product | json }}; 

     // Listen to radio button updates and trigger a function to identify the variant
     $('.option').change(function() {
        idSelectedVariant();
     });

     function idSelectedVariant(){
         //1. Loop through the options and identify the selected options
         //2. Once the selected options are identified, loop through the variants in the productData object and identify the selected variant by checking the variant options
         //3. Keep in mind that not all product variants are going to have 3 options all the time. Some products can have 1 or 2 options as well.
         //4. Once the relevant variant is identified display the variant price by updating the content in the variantPrice span.
     }
  });
</script>
```